# Why did he have to let go?

Tags: gravity

In Gravity, when they get back to the ISS, she was barely holding onto him, but they were both stopped.  Why, then, did he have to let go or otherwise he'd pull her with him?  As far as I could tell, their momentum, at least in relation to the ISS, had been stopped.